# How to search for a phrase in a RichTextBox and highlight every instance of that phrase with a color you specify

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How can one search for a phrase in a RichTextBox and highlight every instance of that phrase with any color desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the string assigned to ValToSearchFor and the color assigned to the RichTextBox's SelectionColor property as desired.

```
String richText = richTextBox1.Text;
String ValToSearchFor = "duckbilledPlatypus";
int pos = 0;
pos = richText.IndexOf(ValToSearchFor, 0);
while (pos != -1) {
    richTextBox1.Select(pos, ValToSearchFor.Length);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    pos = richText.IndexOf(ValToSearchFor, pos + 1);
}
```

Comment: In order to support large texts you can only look in the characters that are visible on the screen. This might improve performance on large texts. Many syntax highlighting engines do that.